# What's name of mylocation icon

Tags: android, google-maps, icons

What's name of mylocation icon or where can I found it?
I'want override screen with map and want move this icon down. For this I off automatic icon and create my ImageView in layout. But I need my_location_icon.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The drawable is called ic_menu_mylocation

You can also find it here: [ic_menu_mylocation](https://github.com/SammysHP/cgeo/diff_blob/86e9f395d67dc657d654a903a55e6bdfec0034bd/main/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_menu_mylocation.png?raw=true)

Comment: but how about border and transparent layout? I need do this myhends?

Comment: I assume this "transparant layout" is just another imageview which is placed under the location image

Answer (score 0):

You can download official android icons from here : [Android Design Icons](http://developer.android.com/downloads/design/Android_Design_Icons_20130926.zip)

Unzip the folder -> Action_Bar_Icons -> Holo light/Holo dark -> 07_location_location_found

In this folder you will find my location icon for different densities(mdpi, hdpi, etc.).

Every android developer should have this set of icons.

Comment: but how about border and transparent layout? I need do this myhends?

Comment: how about border? Yes, I downloaded this folder before and seen this logo. But i think it different, becose this pack has name Action_Bar_Icons

Comment: it is the right icon which is used to display current location or GPS and comes with standard android icons.

Comment: No, it's right icon to show on ActionBar that location founded, but for map is another icon with transparent white color and gray border.